# How are derivatives and integrals inverse functions when they're not injective transformations?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, linear-transformations, inverse-function

By using the kernel of both transformations, we can easily check that they're not injective functions (due to the fact that kernel does not only contain the zero vector by seeing both operators as linear transformations)

So, what am I interpreting wrong? I'm a bit confused on this.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: To define the integral and derivative as inverse functions of each other you must be precise about their domains and codomains. For example, an indefinite integral is not a function because of the constant of integration.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification! I really appreciate it.